# streaming audio with soundmanager2 i need controls

Tags: javascript, controls

I have this code and I worked to perfect it but I put controls. Could anyone help? Thanks

```js
var url = 'http://72.29.70.22:8264/;';
var time = 0;
var timer = $('#Streaming');
var loading = $('#Loading');
var start = new Date;
var seconds = function(){
    var diff = ((new Date).getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000;
    return diff + ' seconds.';
};
var timing = setInterval(function() {
    timer.html(seconds());
}, 100);
soundManager.onready(function() {
    soundManager.createSound({
        id:'Radio', 
        url:url, 
        autoPlay: true,
        onplay: function() {
            clearInterval(timing);
            loading.html('Finished loading');
            timer.html(seconds());
        }
    }); 
});
```

```
## `Heading` ##
```

Comment: you put controls and.. what happened? What's your problem. Please clarify what are you asking. If something doesn't work, write what exactly works in an unexpected manner (or doesn't work at all) and what do you expect from your code.

Comment: Also you created a snippet but it only contains JavaScript, it doesn't even pointed if you use jQuery. Are you asking about how to build HTML for your JavaScript? Or you have HTML, but just haven't inserted it into the post? If so, please insert it.

Comment: hi thanks for responding so quickly the idea is to create controls up and down audio, pause and play to control this sound signal but not how to do'm using inserted in html5 and as responsible for the page is reproduced but I can not put controls I using the library SoundManager2, jquery-1.7.2.min.js, jquery.tools.min.js and SoundManager2-nodebug-jsmin.js

Comment: apologizes for not having explained well what'll try my luck now have the code in <script> in the body of html and web charge when the signal sounds fine but not like putting controls I am using jquery, SoundManager2


A) Yes:
jquery-1.7.2.min.js "
jquery.tools.min.js "
SoundManager2-nodebug-jsmin.js "
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js "

I just need putting on volume control play and pause the html

Comment: Ok, so is it correct that you just have a script which works well to play some track when you put it into an html (which looks empty); but you want to implement some basic controls (play, pause etc)? Are you using the js libs that you downloaded to your server/local machine or you include those from web? In the second case please show the `<script>` tags that you use to include those (put it into the snippet so that we can see how this works).

Comment: <Head>

<Script type = "text / javascript" src = "js / tools / jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> </ script>
<Script src = "js / tools / jquery.tools.min.js"> </ script>
<Script src = "js / tools / SoundManager2-nodebug-jsmin.js"> </ script>
<Script src = "../ ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </ script>
</ Head>

<Body>
<Script>
here the code already up and running
</ Script>

</ Body>

  Bookstores are downloaded on my machine thanks for your quick response
Traductor de Google para empresas:Google Translator ToolkitTraductor de sitios web

Comment: **help me please**

Comment: hola como puedo poner controles en javascript